# how to manage scrolling of table view containing text fields

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I try to scroll and edit the cells at the bottom of the UITableView, I can't manage to get my cells properly positioned above the keyboard. Actually keyboard hides half of the table view.

Also i created a custom cell class separately for my cells. So text fields delegates are available on that class only. i can't use them in my table biew's view controller

I have seen many answers talking about changing view sizes,etc... but none of them has worked nicely so far.

could anybody help me with this with a piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to adjust the scrollView component of the UITableView. Set your view controller to respond to Keyboard notifications. Like this :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then create a keyboardWillShow: function and adjust the tableview by manipulating the tableView.scrollview.contentOffset (it might be tableView.contentOffset im not near xcode). Make sure you make a keyboardWillHide function to adjust it back to 0,0.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this now (don't know how long this has been available): if you're overriding viewWillAppear, make sure to include at the top

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

I was all set to start listening to keyboard events and setting and removing constraints and just this one line eliminated all that other code.